How can I execute a specific method at the point when a subscription is completed in Spring,Websocket
I want to execute a specific method at the exact moment when the subscription is actually completed, not when the subscription request is made.
For example
 @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {

       StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
...
chattingService.sendEnterMessage(chattingRoomId,loginId);

And
@EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketSubscribeListener(SessionSubscribeEvent event){

        StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

        final Long chattingRoomId = Long.valueOf(headerAccessor.getSubscriptionId());
        final String loginId = headerAccessor.getUser().getName();
...chattingService.sendEnterMessage(chattingRoomId,loginId);

I believe the two methods mentioned above are executed after the subscription request is made.
In those methods, after publishing to the subscribed topic, it seems that during load testing, some messages were published but not received because the subscription wasn't active yet.
Therefore, I want to find a method that executes after the subscription is fully established, rather than just upon the subscription request.
